# How to retrieve all records from nested array in mongodb

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel, eloquent

everyone,
I want to retrieve all boards which have a specific owner name from the mongodb database. I am using Laravel

Here is the sample data.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c2e3b853c06144b6038f3e"),
        "name" : "a new board",
        "description" : "fxcb",
        "owner" : {
                "id" : "58bc562553c06113f130bbb3",
                "name" : "Joker"
        },
        "slug" : "a_new_board",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T17:34:48.628Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T17:34:48.628Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c3097b53c06144b6038f40"),
        "name" : "Board by Tom Cruise",
        "description" : "afgf",
        "owner" : {
                "id" : "58c3090b53c06144b6038f3f",
                "name" : "Tom Cruise"
        },
        "slug" : "board_by_tom_cruise",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T20:15:55.132Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-10T20:15:55.132Z")
}
```

What i have tried:

```
$boards = Board::where(['owner']['name'],'=', 'Joker');
```

gives the error

> Undefined index: name

and `$boards = Board::where(['owner']['name'],'=', 'Joker');`
 gives the error

> Array to string conversion

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have embedded document not array. You can use dot notation to access embedded `owner` doc. Something like `owner.name = 'Joker'`. The dot notation will work for embedded array too.

Comment: @Veeram `$boards = Board::where(['owner.name'],'=', 'Joker');` not working sir. this is the error `Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\iconv()`

Comment: oh sorry that was just mongo shell syntax. I dont know the php equivalent for that part.